# CSS Bootstrap span height issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a small issue with [a site I have worked on for a while](http://www.hotchinesebabes.com/).

As you see, the images stack on top of each other, I'd like to give them a fixed width and use their natural height from that width, and then place the next image right after.

But I cant seem to achieve it, any help would be appreciated.

What is forcing their height to be at around 30px rather than positioning it after as a block?

**EDIT: The site is safe for work, there are no nude pictures.**

Comment: I'm certainly not going to a site called hot chinese babes while I'm at work. Please post some code

Comment: Despite the URL the site isn't actually NSFW from what I can see.

Comment: Ahh i am sorry, there are no nude pictures or such

Comment: The site is safe for work, there are no nude pictures at all

Comment: Still, posting the code and a screenshot would be far more useful and keep people from being blocked by corporate internet filters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using `<ul><li>` for this purpose, use a series of either floated `<div>`s or just floated `<img>` elements.

You can then set a width on the `img` itself and it will float accordingly next to each other.

Comment: Thanks, i think i found the issue, the other images are getting aligned by the 4 provided with the template